# Apache httpd -2.4.23 compilation fails with make in Solaris 10 server

Tags: solaris

```
# pwd
/Apache/httpd-2.4.23
# ./configure --prefix=/Apache/apache2/ --with-ssl=/usr/local/include/openssl --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/usr/local/share/pcre
```

Configure succeeded with latest openssl 1.0.1t.

Make fails:

```
# make clean
# make
/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2      -DSOLARIS2=10 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE     -I. -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/os/unix -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/include -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/srclib/apr/include -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/srclib/apr-util/include -I/usr/local/share/pcre/include -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/aaa -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/cache -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/core -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/database -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/filters -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/ldap -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/loggers -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/lua -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/proxy -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/session -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/ssl -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/test -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/server -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/arch/unix -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/dav/main -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/generators -I/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/mappers  -prefer-non-pic -static -c vhost.c && touch vhost.lo
make: Fatal error: Don't know how to make target `/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/server/test_char.h'
Current working directory /Apache/httpd-2.4.23/server
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
otarget=`echo all-recursive|sed s/-recursive//`; \
list='  mpm'; \
for i in $list; do \
    if test -d "$i"; then \
        target="$otarget"; \
        echo "Making $target in $i"; \
        if test "$i" = "."; then \
                made_local=yes; \
                target="local-$target"; \
        fi; \
        (cd $i && make $target) || exit 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if test "$otarget" = "all" && test -z 'delete-exports libmain.la  export_vars.h httpd.exp'; then \
    made_local=yes; \
fi; \
if test "$made_local" != "yes"; then \
    make "local-$otarget" || exit 1; \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all-recursive'
Current working directory /Apache/httpd-2.4.23/server
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
otarget=`echo all-recursive|sed s/-recursive//`; \
list='  srclib os server modules support'; \
for i in $list; do \
    if test -d "$i"; then \
        target="$otarget"; \
        echo "Making $target in $i"; \
        if test "$i" = "."; then \
                made_local=yes; \
                target="local-$target"; \
        fi; \
        (cd $i && make $target) || exit 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if test "$otarget" = "all" && test -z 'httpd shared-build '; then \
    made_local=yes; \
fi; \
if test "$made_local" != "yes"; then \
    make "local-$otarget" || exit 1; \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all-recursive'
```

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: `--with-ssl=/usr/local/include/openssl` looks wrong.  Where is `openssl` installed?  I doubt there's any `/usr/local/include/openssl/bin/openssl` binary or `/usr/local/include/openssl/include/openssl/openssl.h` header file.

Comment: Actually the solaris system installed with old version(0.9.7d) of openssl in the path "/usr/sfw/bin/openssl" . The latest apache http requires latest openssl version, so we installed externally to this above location "/usr/local/include/openssl"

Comment: Yes, we have a binary in this location "/usr/local/include/openssl/bin/openssl"

Comment: #./configure --prefix=/Apache/apache2 --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/Apache/pcre-8.30  --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.1t

#gmake

-I/d0/workspaces/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/modules/mappers  -prefer-non-pic -static -c vhost.c && touch vhost.lo
make: Fatal error: Don't know how to make target `/d0/workspaces/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/server/test_char.h'
Current working directory /d0/workspaces/Apache/httpd-2.4.23/server
*** Error code 1

Comment: We have upgraded our openssl version to 1.0.1t, Still facing fatal error.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated